# Can't upload contract to my own testnet

Tags: testnet

So I am able to compile my program (It generates the hello.abi and the hello.wast) but when I try to add it the the blockchain that I am running I get:

```
cleos set contract exchange hello.wast hello.abi
```

**ERROR:**

```
25695ms thread-0   main.cpp:2555                 main                 ] Failed with error: Assert Exception (10)
!wast.empty(): no wast file found hello/hello.abi
```

Of course the hello.abi file and the hello.wast files are there! I know that the blockchain is running OK because If I browse to http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info I get:

```
{"server_version":"d7dff4f1","chain_id":"706a....
```

I am following the tutorials on github, running all this through Docker. All thought are welcome

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

- The cleos command is accessing the relevant wallet and blockchain service
- 'exchange' is an account created on your blockchain and your authorised to use such account like having it's keypair in your wallet service.

Try throwing in the full path to your contract rather than the individual wast & abi file.

E.g. If your working directory is `/home/john/contracts/hello/` then run

`cleos set contract exchange /home/john/contracts/hello/ -p exchange`